# What have to do for reconnection in winsock with c++

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, winsock2

I work on socket communication with relay. If connection has lost, i want to reconnect to relay and get last data that sent from relay. I have tried unplug the ethernet cable that i got connection error after that plug in ethernet cable than close socket and reopen socket after that connect again than call receive function but it waits for data from relay, cannot get last data from relay. After that i tried again without closesocket , `it returns -1` . After that i tried do nothing and reconnect ethernet cable to computer. `It returns -1`. There are any way for do that and If connection lost, should i reopen socket and reconnect with connect function or something else ?

Comment: Will the "relay" resend data? Is it documented that it will do that? And what is this "relay", and how has it been configured? Note that "resending" isn't part of TCP, it's something that have have to implemented in the application protocol.

Comment: mode  Vamprelay and it has been configured 61850 protocol, relay does not send again after reconnection.

Comment: Kinda hard to follow. In short TCP doesn't have a means to resend if it gets an entirely new connection, it is up to the application to determine what if anything must be resent and do it.

Comment: It is the relay's responsibility to keep track of any data that fails to send due to disconnect, so it can resend the data after a reconnect. There is nothing you can do in your code to make the relay behave that way, it has to be handled in the relay's implementation.

Comment: Okey Thank you , So if i want to reconnect to relay, should i reopen socket than reconnect or something else ? @FireLancer

Comment: To reconnect you need to close the current connection, and connect again. You should not have to recreate the socket itself, only `closesocket` followed by `connect`.